# System process in android is killed by memchecker

Tags: android, xposed

I noticed my android phone sometimes restart the android runtime, without the kernel. I started to search the cause of the restart in the logcat history, and i came across 2 logs which are weird:

```
06-21 11:43:44.334 15259 15396 I MemHandler: Anomaly Detection Mcd Kill android|14785
06-21 11:43:44.335 15259 15396 I MemChecker: PackageName : android , ProcessName : system , Uid: 1000 , Pss : 257.065********MB is over the memory threshold, Kill the process
```

But why is the system process killed? At the moment it uses 359,53 Mb of RAM, so i think the max threshold is changed by something, but why and by what?
I have a Xiaomi Redmi 3S Prime, my phone is rooted and has Xposed Framework installed. It started after i updated to the latest MIUI 8 and Xposed Framework*

I noticed Whatsapp started to sync contacts 1 second before the system crash, and also a process named KernelCpuSpeedReader failed to read `Sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state`
because it couldn't find this file or directory. The KernelCpuSpeedReader bug appears many times before the crash in the logcat stream

*The only need to update Xposed is because since 3 or 4 system updates the old Xposed (by SolarWarez) became not compatible with MIUI 8. The only change in the framework is the repair of the compatibility

I use MIUI 8 Global Developer versions, now 7.6.15